# PDF scraping -> MS Access

Tags: java, sql, pdf, jdbc, prepared-statement

Over the last few days I have been experimenting with little bits of java code (via PDFBox) to scrape data from a PDF from, and made a little bit of test code to insert test data into a access database.

My ultimate aim is to have a program which takes input of several PDF's (all the same form) insert the data from the PDF to the database, where the data from each form is a new record. Note note all fields need to come across - just most of them.

My question however is about best practise - the best way to approach this in terms of the actual mapping of the fields from the PDF form to the database....I suppose it could be called dynamic SQL generation.

My form probably has about 150 fields, and rather than hard coding pdf.name1-> db.name1 I was thinking perhaps of reading the field names from the pdf with a do while loop and then writing to the database if and only if there is a corresponding field (the database will only have the fields that I need)

I hope this information is specific enough, though the question is really about design philosophy. Having said that if anyone wants to insert specific code examples I will gratefully receive them)

Cheers

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, your insert will look probably something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO sometable (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)
```

So how to get there?

1 - Map your PDF (you already have that):

```
//Will contain (fieldname, value) for all fields found in your PDF
Map<String,String> pdf = new HashMap<String,String>();
//Fill it (you already have that)
```

2 - Find out what columns you have in your table (I assume you use [ucanaccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) for JDBC to your access DB)

```
  List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFileSpec);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "] WHERE False")) {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("Column names as reported by ResultSetMetaData:");
        for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
            columns.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
        }            
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

3 - put it together

```
 StringJoiner col = new StringJoiner(",");
 StringJoiner val = new StringJoiner(",");
 //First Iteration: Create the Statement
 for(String c : columns) {
   //Your PDF has a matching formfield 
   if(pdf.hasKey(c)) {
     col.add(c);
     val.add("?");
   }
 }
 String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s)", col.toString(), val.toString());
 try(PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
   //Insert position in statement
   int pos = 0;
   //Second iterations: Bind the values to the statement
   for(String c : columns) {
     //Your PDF has a matching formfield 
     if(pdf.hasKey(c)) {
       insert.setString(++pos, pdf.get(c));
     }
   }
   insert.executeUpdate();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

If you're unlucky though, your column names don't exactly match your pdf form field names - so you would need a mapping `Map` with all the 150 names and their mappings - in which case collecting the column names becomes obsolete as well as you'll calculate them from your PDF names.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I will go through your code and get my head around it. I am using ucanaccess.

I will create the database so the column names do match. 

Cheers

Comment: I understand SELECT * FROM +tablename+ - but why the "WHERE False"  bit on the end of the statement?

Comment: You don't want any data to be returned - just the column definitions - so you return no rows with where false

Comment: Thanks Jan. Also should it be "containsKey(c)" not "hasKey(c)" - I cant find any reference to hasKey?

Also should for (String c : columns) be for (String c ; coulmns)

Thanks again.

Comment: Actually Jan I discovered that insert.executeUpdate() needs to run outside of the for(String c : columns ) { loop.

However when I move it outside of the loop the scope of "insert" is not defined because its outside the loop. How to fix this?

Comment: But it *is* outside the for loop in the code I provided?! Just don't pull it out of the try block or the variable will be unknown / out of scope

Comment: I have used your code as a base and expanded on it. It works wonderfully. I do have two questions however. Some of the fields on the PDF are date. I was thinking of parsing them to date type before inserting into the database based on  if loop that looks at the PDF field name which will be "anythingDate" ie "startDate, endDate etc...unless you think there is a better way?

Also I am stuck using Java7 - so joiner is out. Not sure how this would be done with guava's one?

Comment: Sorry - clicked the wrong button. I think I fixed it now.
I have used that code over and over again. Thanks.